# AS3 - do functionClassA.call() in a functionClassB with parameters

Tags: actionscript-3, function

I read this : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html
But that does not exactly correspond to what I want to do, and I can't find the right solution. However my question is not so complicated.

Here is the situation :

**mains.as** contains a **functionA(strParam:String)**

**onlineClass.as** contains a functionB working like this :

```
private static functionB (fnParam:Function):void //my fnParam is functionA
{
    var strParam:String = getSomeStringResult(); 
    //I have a result from a function

    fnParam.call(strParam); 
    //I want to execute functionA with strParam as parameter
}
```

But I don't understand what I have to do with call parameters.
I tried :

```
fnParam.call(null, strParam);
```

But it returns an error : 
[Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1009: Impossible to access a property or a method of a null object's reference

I am sure the answer already exists somewhere but a search with "function" and "call" leads nowhere.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: If the only argument for `functionB` is `fnParam` (and you're passing `functionA`), then where are you getting `strParam` from?

Comment: strParam is from the functionB execution that I didn't develop here. I need to pass to functionA the strParam I get when functionB is executed. (should I edit my post to be more clear ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made my code working, and I think it could be a static story. FunctionA is not static, and when I pass it as a parameter of the static FunctionB, this works :

```
private static var functionACallback:Function;

public static functionB( functionA:Function ):void
{
    functionACallback = functionA; //set the static functionACallback
    var strParam = getSomeStringResult(); //get the string
    functionACallback(strParam); //call the static var with parameter
}
```

I don't entirely understand the issue here, but the above code resolve the problem.

defenestrate.me's answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If a parameter is a function then you can call it directly as the parameter name if it's being passed to another function:

```
functionB(fnParam:Function){
    fnParam('strParam');
}
```

The issue here looks like like the functionA is null when it's being passed through to functionB. This is possibly because they're in different files / classes but you'll probably want to debug before functionB is called to make sure functionA is accessible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have still the same error when I try your solution, so functionA could be null. But when I make my code working without the string parameter : fnParam.call(), it's working fine. That is why I don't understand the error.

Comment: From your example it may be worth adding a breakpoint on calling fnParam.call() to make sure strParam has the value you're expecting it to have. Although I'm sure it should still call the function fine even with a null value, it might be worth checking that the return value of getSomeStringResult() isn't causing problems. You'd also be able to see at that point if the fnParam variable is indeed a function and not null.